# Error setonitemselectedlistener

Tags: java, android, android-layout

estoy intentando hacer un `BottomNavigationView` pero cuando le quiero poner el listener no me aparece como una opción y no se que hacer, os adjunto el código. Muchas gracias.

Código de mi layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/main_nav"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_nav"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/main_nav"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_frame"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items" />
```

Código de mi Activity:

```
    public class ListTab extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationItemView mMainNav;
    private FrameLayout mMainFrame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_tab);

        mMainFrame = findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
        mMainNav = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
        mMainNav.bringToFront();
        mMainNav.setOn
    }

}
```

Comment: Si mal no recuerdo **setOnItemClickListener** es para ListView. ¿BotomNavigationItemView es de tipo ListView? Yo diría que no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu clase estas definiendo `private BottomNavigationItemView mMainNav;`y deberia ser:

```
 BottomNavigationView  mMainNav;

mMainNav = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.main_nav);


mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.my_action1:
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: BottomNavigationItemView puede ser una clase suya, no lo sabemos. Y si fuese error "ortográfico" el compilador lo diría, así que opino que el tiene esta clase pero no es la que debe ser.

Answer (score 2):

El widget que estas usando es un `BottomNavigationView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

Por lo tanto **debes definir tu variable del tipo `BottomNavigationView` y no como `BottomNavigationItemView`** :

```
//private BottomNavigationItemView mMainNav;
private BottomNavigationView  mMainNav;
```

de esta forma podras asignar sin problema el listener [OnNavigationItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)